# Graphene lattice - honeycomb or hexagonal

Tags: solid-state-physics, graphene

Wikipedia says, in [its page on hexagonal and honeycomb lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_lattice):

> The honeycomb lattice is a special case of the hexagonal lattice with a two-atom basis. The centers of the hexagons of a honeycomb form a hexagonal lattice, and the honeycomb lattice can be seen as the union of two offset triangular lattices.
> In nature, carbon atoms of the two-dimensional material graphene are arranged in a honeycomb lattice.

But graphene does not have a two-atom basis, so why is it getting called a honeycomb lattice?

I'd think it's more accurate to refer to it as a hexagonal lattice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphene *does* have a two-atom basis. The point is made graphically very clearly in [the Wikipedia page you quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_lattice), which includes this figure:

[image]

The honeycomb lattice includes two different site types, which are labelled in red and green in the image. In graphene, both of these sites are populated with identical carbon atoms, but that is irrelevant to the periodicity of the lattice structure. In essence, there simply is no way to create a proper unit cell (where "proper" here is equivalent to "shaped as a parallelogram") which only includes one green atom and no red atoms (or vice versa) and which tiles the plane as a Bravais lattice.

You can, of course, cut up the unit cell of the Bravais lattice into two equivalent triangular sectors, and tile the plane with those. But the resulting tiling is not a Bravais lattice, which requires every copy of the unit cell to be obtained from the primal unit cell by a displacement of the form $\mathbf d_{n_1,n_2} = n_1 \mathbf a_1 + n_2 \mathbf a_2$ (and, therefore, without any rotations or reflections or additional symmetry operations).

---

That said, of course, when you say

> I'd think it's more accurate to refer to it as a hexagonal lattice.

all honeycomb lattices are also hexagonal lattices, as you should already be aware of (since it is in the quote in your question). But graphene is in the special case, not in the general hexagonal-lattice category.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. So basically two atoms can be "inequivalent"  even if they are identical.  I have a follow-up question. I have read in some places (here on PhysicsStackExchange also:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142553/does-graphene-have-a-honeycomb-lattice)  that it is technically wrong to say that "The Bravais lattice of graphene is clearly not honeycomb".  What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Lost Because the honeycomb lattice *is not a Bravais lattice*.  The point is that the two atoms in the basis have *different* environments: the one on the left has two nearest neighbors above and below to the left, whereas the basis atom on the right has two nearest neighbors and below to the *right*.

Comment: @march "In essence, there simply is no way to create a proper unit cell (where "proper" here is equivalent to "shaped as a parallelogram") which only includes one green atom and no red atoms (or vice versa) and which tiles the plane as a Bravais lattice."          
This statement implies that *if we do include red and green atoms* we will be able to tile the whole lattice as a Bravais lattice.

Comment: @Lost.  Right, and when you do that, you get a *hexagonal* Bravais lattice. The question is, ignoring the fact that there are atoms there, do the *points* at which the atoms sit form a Bravais lattice? And the answer is no, they don't.  You have to *remove* one of those points from each of the unit cells shown in this answer, and what's left is a hexagonal lattice. The problem is partly one of terminology.  We aren't careful when we say "lattice". Perhaps we should say a honeycomb *crystal structure* is a hexagonal *lattice* with a two-atom basis.

Comment: @march Oh, I see. So a crystal structure= Underlying lattice + basis right? Also, can you define Baravais lattice for me? Is it that one of the oblique, square, hexagonal, and rectangular ones are the only Bravais lattices?

Comment: @Lost The definition is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice). It's a set of points that is closed under addition (addition being the vector addition of the position vectors representing those points). Alternatively, it can be defined as the span of a linearly independent set of vectors, but with *integer* coefficients. In either case, you can show that the honeycomb "lattice" doesn't satisfy these conditions. I think we should stop spamming Emilio Pisanty's inbox now though.